# Why do i get an error?

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

This is all writen in python and all of the indents are right on my script but not on this 
post.

what i really need help on is ord('f')

every time i click on it the error says list.remove(x): x not in list

can you please tell me what i am doing wrong

```
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('f'):
                if b in baddies:
                    b['rect'].top < WINDOWHEIGHT
                    baddies.remove(b)
    for b in baddies[:]:
        if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
            baddies.remove(b)


    for b in baddies:
        windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: That example code is way too long. Can you extract just a few lines sufficient to show the problem?  No one but the very bored will want to go through all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. It says that `b` is not in `baddies`, so you can't delete it. One way to solve this is checking if `b` is in `baddies`. If it is, then delete it:

```
if b in baddies:
    baddies.remove(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Thank you for your help i solved it with a variation of yours.

```
removeCheat = False
**if event.key == ord('f'):
    removeCheat = True**

*if not reverseCheat:
    baddieAddCounter += 1*

**for b in baddies[:]:
    if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
        baddies.remove(b)
    elif removeCheat:
        if b in baddies:
            while b in baddies:
                if b['rect'].top < WINDOWHEIGHT:
                    baddies.remove(b)**
```